# Websocket Yii2 падает

Tags: yii2, websocket

У меня проект на Yii2. Так же установил сервер вебсокетов - [ссылка](http://satirics.net/wp/2015/09/22/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-websocket-%D0%B2-yii2/)

Но есть одна проблема: он через часа 2-3 перестает принимать сообщения. 
В чем может быть причина?